# How to get System Icons on Mac through Node

Tags: javascript, objective-c, node.js, macos

I've been looking for a way to get the system set icons for paths.

For e.g

> /Applications/TextEdit.app
>   /test.docx
>   /test/folder

On windows i achieved this by using a C# CLI program to generate Base64 pngs of icons for paths, and then call it synchronously in Node...

Answer (score 0):

Given the path to the file (filePath), just call this:-

```
NSImage *image = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] iconForFile:filePath];
```

Comment: Any idea how to do the exact same in NodeJS?

Comment: Sorry, I don't. I answered because you tagged the question with objective-c